# need to store a bunch of constant integer values, class with just const or something better?

Tags: c#

I am making a class with a bunch of constant integer fields.

Any better ideas to doing it this way?  maybe a struct would be better? if so, why?

This won't ever change, and will need to be referenced in the web application throughout.

Comment: What are the integers used for?

Answer (score 4):

If you are creating a type whose sole purpose is to contain a set of constant integers, or any other constant / static data, then a static class in C# is the best choice.  It is designed specifically for the purpose of only containing static data / methods.

```
public static class Constants { 
  public const int SomeValue = 42;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How do you mean *constant*? Do the values just not change within one instance or in the whole programm?

In the latter case, you should consider an `enum`.

```
public enum Foo {
    bla = 42
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the value will never ever change, constants works fine. The compiler will substitute the reference to the constant with the literal value, so you get the same performance as if you put the value directly in the code.

If the values might need to change in the future, you may want to use a property instead:

```
public static int Answer { get { return 42; } }
```

If you use the property from a different project, and later recompile the project where the property is and just deploy that dll, the application will use the new value. If you would have used a constant instead, you have to recompile the entire application.

Comment: This is a verbose solution but the most flexible down the road. i have been using it of late. One thing i would add to Guffa's example is to make it a static property rather than an instance and i would also make the containing class static to enforce everything to be static. This gives you enum-style access to your values but with all the flexibility of a class.

Comment: @psasik: Good point, the property should of course be static.

Answer (score 2):

What do the integers represeent?

If they are hard valued items that never change, consider perhaps an enum?

Other options would be a static class, if you never need to actually instantiate the class to use the integers.

It would definitely help if we need what the integers were used for.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing an enum that inherits from int:

```
public enum Values : int
{
     ValueOne = 1,
     ValueTwo,
     ValueThree,
     ...
}
```

If you specify the first value as 1, then ValueTwo will be 2, ValueThree will be 3, etc. It automatically increments all values after an explicitly specified value, until you explicitly specify another value.

To get the int value, you just cast it:

```
int value = (int)Values.ValueOne;
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer `static readonly`, but that's due to obfuscation from my side.

Comment: There is a difference.  static readonly can still be modified from the static constructor.

Comment: Indeed, but thats the point for me. You cannot obfuscate a const.